# npm run build makes build/, complains it already exists

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I'm building an ASP.NET Core app with React in Visual Studio. When I run `npm run build`, I get the following error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\[redacted]\ClientApp]\build\static\js'
```

I've deleted the `build` folder and run again, but it creates it and then complains again that it already exists.

Here's my package.json:

```
  "name": "partssearchtool",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "recharts": "^2.1.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "synp": "^1.9.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "nan": "^2.14.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start"` but `"build": "react-scripts build"` - prefixed the wrong script? Note you can also use `"pre<script>"` and `"post<script>"` in the `"scripts"` map for these kinds of task.

Comment: This is just what came out of the box from Visual Studio. Should I remove the `rimraf ./build`?

Comment: Well what that does is delete the build directory, which react-scripts start doesn't populate to begin with, but which react-scripts build is complaining about. So I guess someone messed up.